# Show that $T = \{f \in C[0,1] :\, \int_0^1f(x)\,dx = 0 \}$ is a subspace of $C[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Show that $T = \{f \in C[0,1] :\, \int_0^1f(x)\,dx = 0 \}$ is a subspace of $C[0,1]$.

So far I've shown that the $0$ vector is in $T$. But how do I prove that it's closed under addition?

Comment: What does a general element in $T$ look like? What does the sum of those two elements look like?

Comment: Additivity? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Hint: you have a "sum rule" and a "scalar multiple rule" for integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $T$ is closed under addition, you need to prove that if $f,g \in C([0,1])$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x)~dx = 0$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 g(x)~dx = 0$, then $\displaystyle \int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]~dx = 0$.